# Practical analyzing and searching strategies use cases in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm learning about ElasticSearch and enjoying every minute of it. However, there are some practical issues that are confusing me and of course lack of experience that I think seeing some good real life examples might clear up.

Now I am working on a website where I have accounts and products catalog and I want to search for best product matches when end-user searching for products depending on distance, relevance queries  and so many criteria .

Particularly interested in:

- Relevance Scoring and ranking strategies
- Analyzing data of products catalog
- Filtering

I would appreciate any references.

**P.S**

I am using Nest for .net to communicate with ElasticSearch Cluster

Comment: I would highly recommend one of Elastic's developer training courses if you're looking to really dive into this (full disclosure: I work for Elastic): https://training.elastic.co/

Answer (score 1):

Well those three subjects are quite wides. A lot of works has been done on it. You should take some time to look at the elastic search documentation, for your problem, I would recommend you to have a look to the following page first:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html (For the scoring of your document based on the distance)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html (For the filtering)

Concerning your last point, the analysing part, I would recommend that you have a look to Kibana:
https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend this article by Alexander Reelsen — [Implementing A Modern E-Commerce Search](https://spinscale.de/posts/2020-06-22-implementing-a-modern-ecommerce-search.html). Great content on e-commerce product catalogues, filtering, and relevance in general (hint — there's no single optimal approach to achieve "relevance").

Secondly, **I recently published a handbook** for people just like you who need some good real-life examples — you can purchase it at https://elasticsearchbook.com. It contains concise guides on topic like faceted search, filtering, deduplication, autocomplete etc.